# array of list of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need to build a data structure which is a 2D array in which each cell contains a position(of a previous cell) and a float value. Looks something like below:

```
((x1,y1),v1)... ((xl,ym),vn)
.
.
.
((xa,yb),vc)....
```

I know the dimensions of the array, so I thought it would be easier to make it a 2D array, in which each column is a list. Is there another elegant way of doing this? Also, I am unsure if I can append a list to an array. Am I heading in the right direction?

edit: for clarification
I need to make a array of list of tuples. Each tuple is of the form ((row_position,column_position),some_float_value). The list will contain some n number of these tuples. And each list needs to be a column of an array. Which I would be using to backtrace through.I am using something like this to make a viterbi chart for HMMs.

```
     word1 word2 word3..
tag1 tuple1 tuple2 tuple3..
tag2 tuple1 tuple2 tuple3..
.
.
.
```

Comment: Could you add a more specific example? I don't quite understand what you intend to do

Comment: Edited the questions

Comment: is your list always 2 elements, the first one a 2-element tuple, and then one more number?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a matrix (really a list of lists) you can use this:

```
data = [
    [((0, 0), 0.0)
     for j in range(5)]
    for i in range(10)]
```

Or the same thing:

```
data = []
for i in range(10):
    row = []
    for j in range(5):
        cell = ((0, 0), 0.0)
        row.append(cell)
    data.append(row)
```

---

This could be used like this:

```
>>> data[0][2]                 # get data for row 0, column 2
((0, 0), 0.0)

>>> data[0][5][0][1] = 555     # change data
>>> data[0][5][1] = 7.4        # change data
>>> data[0][5]
((0, 555), 7.4)
```